# Regex to identify decimal between 0.00 and 10.00

Tags: html, regex, mask, masking

I would like to validate values. The values are between 0.00 <= x <= 10.00 but i don't understand how to .
How do I do it? 
I want to do that.

```
0.00 yes
0.10 yes
0.1  no
9.99 yes
10.00 yes
10.01 no
```

And i wrote that regex statement

```
^((0\.[0-9]{1})|(10\.00))$
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use following regular expression:

```
^\d(\.\d+)?$|^10(\.0+)?$
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/tB4wY8/1

Answer (score 1):

YJ Lee's answer is close, but after understanding your requirements, the regular expression isn't quite what you're looking for.  I [forked their regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uA0vO1/2) and came up with this:

`^(\d\.\d{2}|10\.0{2})$`

Comment: Yes, according to the examples, the decimal point is not optional, and there must be exactly two digits after it.  Some feedback from the OP would be nice, though...